# ECSlidingViewController - adding UITableView and segue to another ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, ecslidingviewcontroller

I am trying to create push segue from view. Maybe image would be best for describing:
[image: Storyboard of my application]

I started from sample ECSlidingViewController project (BasicMenu) and I am trying to expand first ViewController (Home) to another ViewController. I get it and I can go from selected row in tableView to the controller. But when I am in controller and I tap on Back I am at different screen from first one (it's blank screen with button at upper left). I guess I must set something more to get this working but I don't know what. Thanks

**Updated:**
Code from first view controller to go to next view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Find the selected cell in the usual way
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.searchResultsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"selectedSegue" sender:cell];
}
```

Comment: I added some lines of code but I am not sure what I should add more. I  added second view controller. I add push segue from first controller from tableView to second view controller and I added lines of code which are at my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is with code in method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. When I removed it. The segue is performed well and I go to other view controller and when I tap on top left button I get back where I was. It's okay.

So I guess the real problem was with `sender` in `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

But I need send to new controller some information about selected row. So I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9736559/367593).